# Angular JS with Require JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, requirejs

I am using requireJs with Angular Js , Into my require-config file i bootstrapped the application as follows:

require([
    'angular',
    'app'
    ], function(angular, app) {

```
     //   alert('sd');
    var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);
    angular.element().ready(function() {
        // bootstrap the app manually
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['iStickers']);
                     alert('test');
    });
}
```

when I am trying to use the function to change language in my application,

```
 'use strict';
define([
    'angular',
    'angularRoute',
       // 'resource'
], function(angular) {
    alert('ww');
    var loginModule = angular.module('iStickers.login',['ngRoute','ngResource'])

        loginModule.service('translationService',[ function($resource) {
alert('3');
      this.getTranslation = function($scope, language) {
        var languageFilePath = 'translation_' + language + '.json';
        console.log(languageFilePath);
        $resource(languageFilePath).get(function(data) {
          $scope.translation = data;
        });
      };
    }]);



    loginModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        });
    }])
    loginModule.controller('loginCtrl', 'translationService', ['$scope', function($scope, translationService) {

   $scope.selectedLanguage = 'no';
   $scope.translate();
    }]);
```

it gives me an error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginCtrl' is not a function, got string
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/ng/areq?p0=loginCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string
>   minErr/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js:63:12